# Letting user export their data from Firebase database?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a pretty run of the mill Firebase database, and I'd like the user to be able to export their data in JSON format. I noticed that if you go into the realtime database console on Firebase the admin can export as JSON, so I'm curious if it would be possible to have some sort of URL that the user can access if they are authenticated in order to be able to retrieve their own user data..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once developed an application with an option that allows the user to export the data to a txt file on the device storage. So if you think that this option can help you, please use the following code:

```
try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myFolder");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File myFile = new File(root, "myFileName.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myFile);
    writer.append(text);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might want to change the name of the folder that will be created to store all of your exported txt files from `myFolder` with a particular one. You might also want to change the filename `myFileName` with a particular one.

Hope it helps.